# My touchpad stopped working

Tags: 20.04

My touchpad stopped working fortunately my laptop has touchscreen I was able yo find several fixes which helped but now my touchpad isnt working correctly I cant scroll I cant tap basically its a mouse now all the fixes I've got online still don't fix the problem fully. Im new to Linux it was recommended by a friend as a better OS for software programming but seems it was a mistake I've almost had to pend 2 hours a day fixing a bug for the last 3 months. I dont know can anyone help

Comment: There is no information to tell anything. My touchpad works well on all devices.

Comment: Please check out all the touch pad of your laptop . or check your hardware